# Total count of Customer and Customer Ranking by Sale ( Power DAX for show it )

Tags: count, powerbi, dax, rank

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5A88W.png)

i am new in powerBI, and i want to select Customer ID from Slicer, then Matrix can show total no of customer ID , i only can show total no of customer ( but need to select Product / Group ) so i want it total no of customer will base on selected Product / Group to change

at the same time , Customer Ranking by sales is same situation , i only can got the overall ranking of customer by sales but it cannot change when i select product / Group

Could any expert can help me on it????? Thank thank thanks

DAX for total no of customer ,
Total AC = COUNT('AC list'[Customer Code])

For the customer ranking DAX
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7dDm.png)

Both Dax want to change total number when i select Product / Group

Could any expert can help me on it????? Thank thank thanks

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t1N4wjKQiNwaL73d9vv0JDaXPbrLqd52GkL3uuK9j_8/edit?usp=sharing

enter image description here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oh1k.png)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/133gq5YZ-5jNse7NC2NZmppqvEVeEjrAD/view?usp=share_link

Comment: You need to add some sample data and your expected output from them/

Comment: Sorry , just insert back Google sheet link for the data details

Comment: appreciate! you are talking about some columns - Product, Sales, Customer Code in your details but I can not see them in the sample data. Another thing just gives an overview of the output after selecting a customer ID. Maybe you can populate the output in Excel and then just provide the screenshot.

Comment: Sorry again , just screenshot about the slicer & related data for refn, Thank you so much

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't connect your expected output with your given sample data.

Comment: Really sorry for the data shortage and i am preparing a power bi file that can be share with you , really appreciate your patience for my issue , Thanks

Comment: just insert a link for the powerbi data , really looking for the coaching about the DAX , Thanks

Comment: I will try to check the file soon.